# django database error when linking one to one to the user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

im creating an app where i have different users that have some attributes that the user model doesnt have, to do that im extending the user authentication model from django using a oneToone relationship to each different user.

The problem i am having is that when i try to create a user called MusicLover that extends the user model from django i get an error telling me i have a column that doesn't exists which basically is a column called: *the attribute that makes the relation to the user model* + '_id'

here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Genero(models.Model):

    gen_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gen_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.gen_nombre

class MusicLover(models.Model):
    us_fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ml_genero = models.ManyToManyField(Genero)
    ml_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

here is my urls.py file:

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',

```
url(r'^$', 'socialweb.views.index'),
url(r'^registro/$', 'socialweb.views.register'), # ADD NEW PATTERN!
url(r'^registroBanda/$', 'socialweb.views.registerBand'),
url(r'^registroEvento/$', 'socialweb.views.registerEvent'),
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'auth/login.html'}),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
)
```

here is the method that calls ^registro$ which is register in my view.py file

def register(request):
    registered = False

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    musiclover_form = MusicLoverForm(data = request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid and musiclover_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        musiclover = musiclover_form.save(commit=False)
        musiclover.ml_us_id = user
        musiclover.save()

        registered=True
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:

        print user_form.errors, musiclover_form.errors

else:

    user_form = UserForm()
    musiclover_form = MusicLoverForm()

return render(request, 'registro.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'musiclover_form':musiclover_form, 'registered':registered})
```

and finally here are the forms that i have to create the user:

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    #email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name')
class MusicLoverForm(ModelForm):
    #us_fecha_nacimiento = forms.DateField(label='fecha de nacimiento')
    class Meta:
        model = MusicLover
        fields = ('ml_genero','us_fecha_nacimiento')
```

the error im getting is the following:

**table socialweb_musiclover has no column named user_id**

please if someone can tell why im not able to create users ill appreciate it.

Comment: did you syncdb? did you migrate?

Comment: yes i already did syncdb, what do you mean by migrate?

Comment: Migrations are a tool which will look at whats changed since the last time you updated the database then will only make those changes. For example if you have an existing database table with name which is required, then you want to change it to be the default of null. Then instead of dropping the entire database to syncdb, you can run the migration on the name column. Changing only that column from required to null.

Comment: Are you sure the user record is being created?